# Python regex to findall across multiple lines

Tags: python, regex, csv, screen-scraping

I've tried solving this problem over the past week without making any progress. Any help from y'all is much appreciated.

I've got 1000s of files with the following text:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Location:,,,ADDRESS_HERE_THAT I WANT
BUT IT CAN ALSO BE ACROSS,
MULTIPLE LINES, BUT NOT A SPECIFIC SET OF LINES,
AND IT ENDS AS ABRUPTLY,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

But a few files also have it in this manner

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Location:,,,ADDRESS,IS,IN,ONE,LINE,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I need to extract the uppercase address using regex in Python.

It's technically a CSV file that's been exported by a very old system. It is effectively unusable as a CSV and hence I've opted to extract the string assuming it is a plain-text file.

My current code is this, but I've tried quite a few other combinations without arriving at a working solution.

```
location = re.findall(r'^Location:,,,(.*),,,,,,,,,,,,,\n$|^Location:,,,(.*)[\n.*]{1,2,3,4,5,6},,,,,,,,,,,,,', CSV, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

Am I even close? Or is there a better way to solve this?

I'm grateful for any help here.

Comment: Python version? python 2 or 3?

Comment: There are more effective solutions than using `re` in this case. Are you open to that?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7. Yup, definitely open to using other techniques. After two weeks of pulling my hair out - anything will do!

Comment: Unless you're proficient with regular expression and understand its limit, it is generally not a good idea to apply `re`. See https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Does each file contain exactly one address? I feel like actual example data would be helpful in understanding the problem better. (If data protection is an issue maybe change some words or numbers around.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your provided dummy data:

```py
s = ''',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Location:,,,ADDRESS_HERE_THAT I WANT
BUT IT CAN ALSO BE ACROSS,
MULTIPLE LINES, BUT NOT A SPECIFIC SET OF LINES,
AND IT ENDS AS ABRUPTLY,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Location:,,,ADDRESS,IS,IN,ONE,LINE,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'''
```

You could use the following regex:

```py
matches = re.findall(r'Location:((?:[^,]*,){16})', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

This is what the matches look like:

```py
>>> print('\n\n'.join(matches))
,,,ADDRESS_HERE_THAT I WANT
BUT IT CAN ALSO BE ACROSS,
MULTIPLE LINES, BUT NOT A SPECIFIC SET OF LINES,
AND IT ENDS AS ABRUPTLY,,,,,,,,,,

,,,ADDRESS,IS,IN,ONE,LINE,,,,,,,,,
```

What to do next depends on the meaning of the commas in the original file. For example, you might want to replace them with spaces:

```py
addrs = [match.replace(',', ' ').strip() for match in matches]
```

Which looks like this:

```py
>>> print('\n\n'.join(addrs))
ADDRESS_HERE_THAT I WANT
BUT IT CAN ALSO BE ACROSS 
MULTIPLE LINES  BUT NOT A SPECIFIC SET OF LINES 
AND IT ENDS AS ABRUPTLY

ADDRESS IS IN ONE LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea: You can use simple looping to detect and extract the multi-lines location data

```
# Test data
TEXT=""",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Location:,,,ADDRESS_HERE_THAT I WANT
BUT IT CAN ALSO BE ACROSS,
MULTIPLE LINES, BUT NOT A SPECIFIC SET OF LINES,
AND IT ENDS AS ABRUPTLY,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Location:,,,ADDRESS,IS,IN,ONE,LINE,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
"""

in_location = False
tmp_location = None

def extract_location(l):
    global in_location
    global tmp_location
    if l.startswith("Location:"):
        in_location = True
        tmp_location = []
        # special case
        if l.endswith(',,,,,,,,,,,,,'):
            print(l[13:-13])
            in_location = False
        else:
            tmp_location.append(l[13:]) # Don't need 'Location:,,,'
    else:
        if in_location:
            tmp_location.append(l)
            if l.endswith(',,,,,,,,,,,,,'):
                # The end
                in_location = False
                res =  " ".join(tmp_location)
                print(res[0:-13])  # Remove trailing commas


def main():
    for line in TEXT.split("\n"):
        extract_location(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

let's say it is saved to a file called `concept.py`,

```
$ python3 concept.py
DDRESS_HERE_THAT I WANT BUT IT CAN ALSO BE ACROSS, MULTIPLE LINES, BUT NOT A SPECIFIC SET OF LINES, AND IT ENDS AS ABRUPTLY
DDRESS,IS,IN,ONE,LINE
```